# Building a sorted array efficiently from a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have an array saved in the disk in binary file with length `N`. Each element of the array is **unique** and has value between `1` to `N`, inclusive. All values between `1` to `N` **present** in the array. I want to make a function in C++ that receives a vector of indices (zero-based), `idx` of length `n`, and return the sorted elements from the binary file taken at the indices.

Example:

```
// saved_array = [2,6,4,10,7,1,9,3,5,8] with N = 10

idx = [0,5,8]; // zero-based index
readAndSortedArray(idx); // returns [1,2,5]
```

The 0th element is `2`, the 5th element is `1`, and the 8th element is `5`. Variable `idx` is always sorted, but the saved array is not sorted. The length of `idx` is about 1% of `N` and typical value of `N` is 10,000.

My code is currently as below.

```cpp
vector<int> readAndSortedArray(vector<int> idx) {
    vector<int> elements(idx.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++) {
        elements[i] = read_element_from_file(idx[i]);
    }
    sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());
    return elements;
}
```

As the function will be called many times (million times), I would like to implement it efficiently.

Any ideas on how to improve the algorithm above?

Some of my ideas are:

- put the new element into the correct position directly (i.e. after reading an element from the file, do binary search for the new element, and put the new element on that position), but this will run in `O(n^2)` time (as one insertion needs `O(n)` time)
- create an empty array of size `N`, flag the position of the new element, and at the end pull out the elements from the array which is non-zero, this will run in `O(N)` time.

Comment: A [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) would sort as you store.

Comment: `std::set` should do the job

Comment: @Muscampester `std::priority_queue` will not provide full functionality needed.

Comment: @Fureeish `std::set` has the same asymptotic complexity as `std::sort`, but much larger constant. It's much better to store all elements in `std::vector` and then `std::sort` them than insert and erase from `std::set`.

Comment: Do your know all the query sets before your start your calculation?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but would sorting the writing code make sense?

Comment: I would says that bottleneck is the IO to retrieve data from file. Can you cache the array from the file ?

Comment: You could use parallelization since the bottleneck is CPU here and your function calls are independent.

Comment: @AndreySScherbakov yes, we know all the queries beforehand.

Comment: @n.m. the elements in array only has value between 1 to N, but the index is zero-based, so it can be 0.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 yes, we are also doing parallelization, but we wonder if we could speed up the algorithm for one process.

Comment: OK it looks like I misread the problem statement, sorry.

Comment: BTW, you may pass `vector<int> idx` by const reference instead of by value.

Comment: You may want to try radix sort as the range of values is small.

Comment: using iterators instead of indexing (`elements[i]`, `idx[i]`) should also give some speed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest optimization idea here is to read an array once and then reuse it:

```
vector <int> readArray() { /* some code to read it from file */ }

vector<int> sortedArray(const vector<int>& arr, const vector<int>& idx) {
    vector<int> elements(idx.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++) {
        elements[i] = arr[idx[i]];
    }
    sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());
    return elements;
}
```

and then somewhere

```
vector<int> arr(readArray());
for (/* yor loop */) {
    ....
    some_vec = sortedArray(arr,some_idx)
    ....
}
```

Comment: It would help to have a guarantee like _element_ <= `USHRT_MAX`/`(unsigned short)~0`/`std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max()`. (Expecially if there were terabytes of (non-unique) elements: memory map when not _forced_ to read.)